# "The document could not be saved, as it was not possible to write to" Error Message from Kile under MikTeX in Win10?

Tags: editors, kile

Recently an occasional but not infrequent error message from Kile under MikTeX in Windows10 seems getting annoying, "The document could not be saved, as it was not possible to write to 'the path of the source file'". I cannot figure out even a flimsy reason for this message: If the error is truthful, then I should get the same message time after time and hence could not even proceed with Kile; otherwise, I should not get any message at all.

I am asking for a fix for this problem; thanks.

Comment: Is the folder of your document synced to some dropbox or alike?

Comment: @samcarter, Oh, it is Google Drive. That is a possible cause you are saying?

Comment: I don't know if this is the root of the problem (no kile user), but this is sometimes a problem for other editors.

Comment: @samcarter, Thanks for the tip. I turned it off and so far it has been fine. Is there a way to keep doing backing up without interrupting the work?

Comment: Personally I prefer to use a version control system and sync this to gitlab as backup for my tex documents.